Theorized tone of two engines combined
Assume 2 of the exact same engine types at the same rotational speed producing the same tone. Lets say the exhaust of each engine gets combined in a uniform length y pipe into one output.
If these two engines were combined in the y pipe, would the sound coming out be different than just one engine? Would the harmonics change? Would it sound like the same engine but just louder in amplitude?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

if you do it "right" - exactly the same frequency tones producing a standing wave in the exhaust pipe, at least one of the engines may (will) stall...

You might be better asking on the Motor Vehicles Stack Exchange.

The "tone" produced by an engine exhaust depends on the size and shape of the exhaust pipe, which will amplify some frequencies from the engine noise and will supress others. So if you combine two separate exhaust pipes into one you will definitely change the perceived sound of the engine. More than that cannot be said without knowing the exact shape of the exhaust.
